# TFS Build Server 2017 Ignores Project Dependencies

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2017 to build a solution that has three projects linked to it. Two of the projects are located elsewhere in TFS. When I build the main project which depends on the other two projects I get errors because the other two projects are not being build. How can I force TFS to build all dependent projects?

Comment: "Two of the projects are located elsewhere in TFS". Are they still in the same project ? If so, does Your build even pull theese Projects too ? do you use GIT or TFVC?

Comment: Hi @D.J. Yes, the two other project are in the same project. We are using TFVC. I have a build definition that builds the main project. Do I need to make a build definition for the two other projects as well? Will they be triggered when the main project is built?

Comment: You can do it with one BuildDefinition. Are you really building the main-project ? If all 3 projects are linked in the Solution you should build the Solution.

Comment: The solution is located under folder A along with the main project and I created a build definition for A. The two other projects are located under folder B. All three projects are within this solution. In the solution parameter in the build process stepI have the following value: $/A/MySolution.sln

Comment: And your build is pulling folder B as well ?

Comment: No, I assumed this would be automatically done by scanning the dependencies of the solution. How can I have the same definition pull folder B?

Comment: Nope. Inside your BuildDefinition go to "Get sources". There you have the "Workspace mappings". You can Add FolderB there

Comment: Thanks! But does this mean I have to add sources to the definition file anytime the solution has added a new project to it?

Comment: If a new folder is required you have to add this, yes. But i would recommend you to rethink the structure of your projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Visual Studio Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build) task you could either build the whole solution by select `.sln` or only build MSBuild project (.*proj) files.

If you select the `.proj` file in the build task, for building three different  projects, you also need to add three tasks.

In your case, since you have selected `.sln` file, TFS will auto build the whole solution including all projects under it. But in the workspace mappings, you need to make sure that you **Map all folders that contain files that your build process requires.** For example, if you add another project, you might have to add another mapping to the workspace.

> So it would **not** be automatically done by scanning the dependencies
>   of the solution. You have to also add Folder B mappings in the get
>   sources of the definition.

- Besides if this is a CI build, in most cases you should make sure
  that these mappings match the filter settings of your CI trigger on
  the [Triggers tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers).
- For more information on how to optimize a TFVC workspace, see
  [Optimize your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace).